# Bash shell script to extract archive

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, tar

I am trying to convert the following script which I use to create archives into one which extracts them.

```
[[ $# -lt 2 ]] && exit 1

name=$1; shift
files=("$@")

#exclude all files/directories that are not readable
for index in "${!files[@]}"; do
   [[ -r ${files[index]} ]] || unset "files[index]"
done

[[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]] && exit 1    

if tar -czvf "${name:-def_$$}.tar.gz" "${files[@]}"; then
   echo "Ok"
else
   echo "Error"
   exit 1
fi
```

So far I have this:

```
[[ $# -lt 1 ]] && exit 1

files=("$@")

#remove files and directories which are not readable
for index in "${!files[@]}"; do
        [[ -r ${files[index]} ]] || unset "files[index]"
done

[[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]] && exit 1

if tar -xzvf "${files[@]}".tar.gz; then
        echo "OK"
else
        echo "Error"
        exit 1
fi
```

I dont know whether I needed to keep the shift as for this script I do not need to discard any arguments. I want to be able to take them all and unzip each one. Also I see there is a -C switch which allows the user to choose where the unzipped files go. How would I go about also adding this as an option for the user because they may or may not want to change the directory where the files get unzipped to.

Answer (score 1):

You unfortunately can't just do `tar -xzvf one.tar.gz two.tar.gz`. Straightforward approach is to use a good old `for` loop:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
   tar -xzvf "$file"
done
```

Or you can use this:

```
cat "${files[@]}" | tar -xzvf - -i
```

---

You can have the first argument to be the specified directory for the `-C` option:

```
[[ $# -lt 2 ]] && exit 1

target=$1; shift
files=("$@")

#remove files and directories which are not readable
for index in "${!files[@]}"; do
   [[ -r ${files[index]} ]] || unset "files[index]"
done

[[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]] && exit 1

mkdir -p -- "$target" || exit 1

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
   tar -xzvf "$file" -C "$target"
done
```

```
./script /some/path one.tar.gz two.tar.gz
```

---

List of files for `tar` can be also constructed like this:

```
target=$1; shift

for file; do
   [[ -r $file ]] && files+=("$file")
done
```

Comment: Well, if `one.tar.gz` contains `two.tar.gz`, it works `:)`

Comment: Could I add an OK echo  before the done and do an else to error an echo?

Comment: @Lenk You can use `if` statement to test any command just like you did in your code. The syntax is: `if cmd; then echo OK; else echo ERROR; fi`.